# Why am I getting a 500 server error on POST?

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2, okhttp

i can't get the Key (token) by post method when i run the app it shows me an error (500) and the response  is null,i tried many times but couldn't find the normal solution.
To be clear i am putting the Hometask and code below:

**So the Hometask is :**

Create one page Authorization, where there are two fields - Partner Login and Password

Partner account for your testing:

Login: login

Password: password

1) **Authorization**:

http://client-api.instaforex.com/Home/GetAPIUsageInfo

You need to get token "RequestMoblieCabinetApiToken".

Request URL: http://client-api.instaforex.com/api/Authentication/RequestMoblieCabinetApiToken

Method: POST

Request:

{

"Login": "PARTNER_LOGIN",

"Password": "PARTNER_PASSWORD"

}

In response you get "passkey" (your token).

**My code:**

> ApiInterface

```
package com.example.instaforexapp.Rest;
import com.example.instaforexapp.Modal.ApiAccount;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Body;
import retrofit2.http.Field;
import retrofit2.http.FormUrlEncoded;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

public interface InstaForexApi {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("api/Authentication/RequestMoblieCabinetApiToken")
    Call<ApiAccount> createAccount( @Field("Login") String login,
                                    @Field("Password") String password);

}
```

> ApiClient

```
package com.example.instaforexapp.Rest;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class ApiClient {

    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://client-api.instaforex.com/";

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getRetrofit() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        httpLoggingInterceptor.level(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor)
                .build();
        if (retrofit == null) {

            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

> ApiAccount Class

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class ApiAccount {

    @SerializedName("Login")
    private String login;

    @SerializedName("Password")
    private String password;

    public ApiAccount(String login, String password) {
        this.login = login;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

}
```

> MainActivity

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.instaforexapp.Modal.ApiAccount;
import com.example.instaforexapp.Rest.ApiClient;
import com.example.instaforexapp.Rest.InstaForexApi;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText txt_login,txt_password;
    private Button btn_confirm;
    public static final String TAG = "com.MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txt_login = findViewById(R.id.txt_login);
        txt_password = findViewById(R.id.txt_pass);
        btn_confirm = findViewById(R.id.btn_confirm);
        btn_confirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String login = txt_login.getText().toString();
                String password= txt_password.getText().toString();
                createAccount(login,password);
                Log.i(TAG, "login :"+login +" password: "+password);

            }
        });


    }

    private void createAccount(String login,String password){
            InstaForexApi api = ApiClient.getRetrofit().create(InstaForexApi.class);
            Call<ApiAccount> call = api.createAccount(login,password);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<ApiAccount>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse( Call<ApiAccount> call, Response<ApiAccount> response) {
                    if (!response.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error: "+response.code(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    ApiAccount account = response.body();
                    String toast = null;
                    if (account != null) {
                        toast = account.getLogin()+" : " + account.getPassword();
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ApiAccount> call, Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });


    }
}
```

Please help to get the "passkey"

Answer (score -1):

500 status code from server means that your server isn't available at the moment now this issues is not at your end so better communicate with your backend team to resolve this. Check this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/http/http_status_codes.htm) to understand about status codes better in server response

Comment: do you mean the problem from their server?, so if the server will be available i will get the key? i mean my code is normal without errors or bugs?

Comment: yeah so connect with someone who is providing this service

Comment: ok bro thank you but they gave me a link for information to know how to get this methods i will copy it,please take a look , i just want to be sure because i'm beginner. http://client-api.instaforex.com/Home/GetAPIUsageInfo
please read the information inside the site, Thank you again

Comment: in this link i can't see the base url

Comment: this is the base url

 private static final String BASE_URL = "http://client-api.instaforex.com/";